# Upload file from C# to SharePoint Online Site when sitename has SPACES

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, issue-tracking

My sharepoint site has spaces in between of ex : https://onshare.sharepoint.com/teams/MainSite/RAM Testing/

List Name : "A Type Folder"

Below Error Message :

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException: Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://onshare.sharepoint.com/teams/MainSite/RAM%20Testing. There is no Web named "/teams/MainSite/RAM Testing/_vti_bin/sites.asmx".
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Could you please help how to pass url with space correctly. This is the code I'm using to pass :

## Try1

`string siteUrl = String.Format("https://onshare.sharepoint.com/teams/MainSite/{0}", Uri.EscapeDataString("RAM  Testing"));`

## Try2

`string siteUrl = https://onshare.sharepoint.com/teams/MainSite/RAM%20Testing/`

thanks in advance. Let me know if anything more is needed.

Comment: How did you create a sharepoint site with space in it, just tried but O365 wouldn't accept it

Comment: my site has been migrated from on premise to sharepoint online maybe then it was allowed.

Comment: @Ives is `RAM Testing` is a subsite/Web. Have you tried listing the Webs in `MainSite`? I suspect the web doesn't have spaces in its URL.

Comment: What API are you trying to call with siteUrl?